# Two different Users and Passwords using JS inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I know this method is not safe, but I'm only using it with a couple of friends, I'm using JS to validate a User and Password to redirect to another page, and it works with 1 User, but I don't know how to add another user, the code is this:

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form name="login" class="login-form">
      <input name="userid" type="text" placeholder="Usuario"/>
      <input name="pswrd" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
      <input id="button" onClick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
        <script language="javascript">
            function check(form) {
                if(form.userid.value == "USER1" && form.pswrd.value == "PASSWORD1") {
                    location.href = "Inicio";
                }
                else {
                    alert("El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos, intente nuevamente")
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `||` to represent OR, e.g.

```
if( (form.userid.value == "USER1" && form.pswrd.value == "PASSWORD1") || (form.userid.value == "USER2" && form.pswrd.value == "PASSWORD2") ) {
```

Comment: Works, is easy and simple, but not elegant :)

Comment: Yeah!! that worked!! I tried that before, but i guess i moved something and didn't work before, but now it does :) Thank you